# Passing an ID into execute method in Scheduled Class

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

Issue is under execute method, we have a sendMailDistribution(Ids) method, here am unable to get ID. It's giving an error like NullPointerException, am unable to rectify this. Can you please help me? What is the issue here?

```
global class WebtoLeadScheduledProcess implements Schedulable
{

     global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){ 
       List<Id> Ids;
       sendMailDistribution(Ids);

  }
     public static void sendMailDistribution(List<Id> Ids){
         CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c mfauser = [SELECT Id, Name, CRS_W2L_Subject__c, CRS_W2L_CC_Email__c, CRS_W2L_c, FROM_Email__c  
                                          FROM CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c 
                                          LIMIT 1];
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
       List<lead> webLead = [SELECT Name, Is_Web_Lead__c, WebToLead_User__c, Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c, RecordType.DeveloperName, leadsource,  status, Company, CRS_City__c, CRS_State_Province__C, CRS_Country__c, CRS_Zip__c, Phone, CRS_Application_Type__c, Comments__c, Email, FirstName 
                            FROM Lead 
                            WHERE Id IN :Ids ];

         Map<String, CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c> emd = new Map<String, CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c>();
         List<CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c> listCodes = CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c.getAll().values(); 

           for(CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c c : listCodes){
               emd.put(c.State_Abbreviations__c, c);
           }
           for (Lead l : webLead ){
                 /* some Code */
```

Comment: May I know from where you are calling the class Scheduler. If yo are scehduling from execute anonymous or using the UI, Then you will be required to query the records. Also Please state the line where you are getting the error. That must be a line where you are trying to use `IDS` variable

Comment: From that place where you are calling a method `sendMailDistribution(Ids)` The `Ids` list is not defined. It is `null`!  So you should to define a list with `Ids` somehow.

Comment: I am scheduling from UI and Can you please tell me the syntax?

Comment: It depends on the Ids that you are trying to pass in. You need to query for the Ids before passing them to `sendMailDistribution` method. If you want to pass in all the Ids from your Lead object: `Ids = [Select id from Lead];`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to schedule from the UI (meaning the Apex class scheduler), then the scheduled class needs to have a way to locate the IDs from a query.

One technique I have used is to create a custom object `MyScheduleParams__c` with at least these fields:

- ClassName (string, unique)
- SOQL (text area long)

Populate a row in this custom object with the classname and the actual SOQL string that will fetch the object Ids you need.  Example: `select id from Lead where status = 'foo'`

Modify the class' execute() method:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){ 
  ID[] lIdList = new List<ID>(); 
  for (Lead l: Database.execute([select soql__c from MySchedulableParams 
                                  where classname__c = 'WebToLeadScheduledProcess' limit 1]))
     lidList.add(l.id);

  sendMailDistribution(lIdList);
}
```

Then, schedule the class normally through the UI.

Thus, the query used by the scheduled job can vary simply by changing the value in the custom object (which could also be changed progammatically by other Apex or even Process Builder)

Note that `global` access modifier is not required unless building a managed package; `public` will suffice.

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy  ?? 'not working at all' -- Unusual to get a thank you for a non-working response. What is not working?

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy - fixed typo in code sample

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: This only works if scheduled using apex code

You need to do something like this:

```
global class WebtoLeadScheduledProcess implements Schedulable
{

 global List<Id> ProcessIds;
 global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){ 
       sendMailDistribution(ProcessIds);
  }
....
```

then you pass the param when you call the scheduled class

```
WebtoLeadScheduledProcess btchProc = new WebtoLeadScheduledProcess();
btchProc.ProcessIds =  wtvYouWant ;
String sch =  '0 0 * * * ?';
System.schedule('WebtoLeadScheduledProcess', sch, btchProc);
```

Comment: In his comment the OP explains "I am scheduling from UI" i.e. there is no way to pass values to the class.

Comment: want to schedule from UI and tried this, still not going any mail.

Comment: @KeithC oops I didn't see that comment, you are right. The only way this works if scheduled using code.